# iPhone 5 UI screen issues

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, ios6, xcode4.5, iphone-5

After lot of googling i am asking this question. I have an app, i want to make it compatible with the iPhone5. I added Default-568h@2x to my app which contains nearly 10views. So I changed views like this..

In viewDidLoad:

```
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height >= 568) {
      self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
    //iPhone5
    }
    else {
    }
window.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

I have made this change in my didFinishLaunching with options:

```
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
```

After doing like this I found Some issues..

1. The bottom of the screen i.e 88px long is not touchable even the controls placed on it - for this i have set FullScreenAtLaunch checked in attributes of MainWindow.xib, but doesn`t worked
2. I have textbox on view, when it is focussed keyboard is coming but on top of the Keyboard  view coming, how to get rid of that.

How to resolve this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This because in the line where you create your `UIWindow` in the App delegate class you will probably have something like this:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
```

change it to something like:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

also where you now do:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height >= 568) {
  self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
//iPhone5
}
else {
}
```

You coud as well do:

```
self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

But most of the time this ins't needed since the view of the viewcontroller will take op the space correctly. If you have set the AutoResizeMasks in interface builder correctly you will not gave to set the frame in code.

Comment: Still the problem lies it the fact that the window is taking up the full height of the screen.

Comment: what should i do to make it interactable and about 2 issue

Comment: It's not interactable because the window height is not correct, post you code where you create the `UIWindow` if create the window via a NIB them make sure that the AutoResizeMakes are set correctly in interface builder.

Comment: I have universal app and and i have added the code to AppDelegare_iPhone, applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Comment: I have xib files not storyboards, even though i have tried either way bot of no use

Comment: The autoresize mask has nothing to do with storyboards, it's available on both storyboards and NIB files. I sugest you start reading the Apple documentation and watch somer WWDC videos about handling resizing views.